# QTP handling Null values with public functions

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to write a QTP Script which works as follows 
* takes a column from table checks if it is null 
if yes 
it adds that column name in a variable .

Later that column name will be used to display to user that all such fields are left blank .
Something like this:

```
Set rsRecordset1 = dbConnection.Execute("select formcd,sndrpstlcd,recppstlcd,sndrcntrycd, from test_data where trk in ('"&tin&"')")

If rsRecordset1.EOF = false Then
Blank_field="blank_fields->"

formcd = rsRecordset1("formcd").value
typcd="formcd"
Call validatenull (typcd,Blank_field)
packaging = rsRecordset1("packaging").value
typcd="packaging"
Call validatenull (typcd,Blank_field)
......

Public function validatenull (typcd,Blank_field)
   If (isnull(typcd) )Then
    Blank_field = Blank_field & " " & typcd &", "
   End If
End Function
```

Value of blank_Field is expected to catch values as "blank_fields->Form_id,packaging (Considering Form_id, Packaging passes Null values) {It shouldnt add values which are not Null to blank_fields}

**In simpler words**

```
ss = Null
call nnn(ss)
Public function nnn(ss)
    If isnull(ss) Then
        msgbox("yes")
    End If
End Function
```

Has Error that msgbox does not populates But,

```
ss= Null 
nnn(ss) 
If isnull(ss) Then 
    msgbox("yes") 
End If
```

Populates Msgbox as Yes 
But I want Case 1 to be working and I do not want to add any more variables to the function name.

IF By making an Array we can do it, please suggest .

Answer (score 1):

It appears your function works fine, but you are passing the wrong values.  From your code snippet:

```
formcd = rsRecordset1("formcd").value
typcd="formcd"
Call validatenull (typcd,Blank_field)
```

When you call 'validatenull', you are passing the variable 'typecd'.  On the previous line, you populate this variable with a string, so it will never be null.  It appears what you intended to pass was the variable 'formcd'.  Your second call to 'validatenull' does the same thing.  Here is your first call modified to use the other variable.

```
formcd = rsRecordset1("formcd").value
typcd="formcd"
Call validatenull (formcd,Blank_field)
```